# Azure : SAML/WS-Fed based identity provider federation with Standard SAML

Tags: azure, saml, idp

First thing first, thank you very much for reading my post ! I am not an Azure expert but I have a lot of expertise when it comes to WAM.

I am facing issues when I try to be the IDP and redirect users to Azure (SP) : when I access the federation (IDP initiated URL) I got the following result in Azure :

"AADSTS50107: The requested federation realm object 'https://*/saml20' does not exist."

The federation SAML/WS-Fed Identity providers issuer is the same 'https://*/saml20' so I am a bit lost. The assertion URL I used as IDP is the generic one, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf" so that may be the issue but I was not able to find a way to generate a metadata from Azure for my IDP.

I was thinking that maybe the issues was related to the attributes in the SAML token so by reading this document (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-saml-tokens
and  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/howto-troubleshoot-sign-in-errors) I modified my setup to push the following attributes :

- NameID : email as  urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent
- http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname : given name as urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified
  -http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname : surname as urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified
- http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name : name as urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified
- AssertionConsumerService : AudienceRectriction with value https://login.microsoftonline.com/MY_TENANT_ID
- http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid : tenant ID as urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified
  -http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/identityprovider : my famous realm 'https://*/saml20'  as urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified

And of course I tried a lot of combination regarding the format to use, data, etc. My problem here is that I am  unsure of what attribute Azure is expecting exactly so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: Yes, and this time Azure is not the IDP. B2C cannot be used for Microsoft SAS service according to the documentation (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sign-in-to-sharepoint-324a89ec-e77b-4475-b64a-13a0c14c45ec) so I don't think we can use it here

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer but I think this is not true (anymore ?) : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-saml-idp